# Using XPath in Nightwatch.js commands to select Polymer Element's child?

Tags: node.js, selenium, xpath, polymer, nightwatch.js

I'm trying to use XPath selectors to target children of Polymer custom elements through nightwatch.js commands. For example:

```
browser
.getAttribute('//th-compare-chart/svg', 'width', function(svgWidth) {

...
})
```

Yields:

```
ERROR: Unable to locate element: "//th-compare-balance-chart/svg" using: css selector
```

The documentation for getAttribute, and other commands, states that you can provide a string selector of either a css selector or xpath:
http://nightwatchjs.org/api#getAttribute

Yet I have not been able to get any xpath selector to work. Does anyone know how to get this to work?

### Update

This is the XML markup, using HTML 5 doctype. The element is built using polymer and according to the inspector is nested inside a strange "#shadow-root". Perhaps it's not possible to access elements inside the shadow-root?

```
<th-compare-balance-chart class="element ">
  #shadow-root
    <core-style>...</core-style>
    <svg id="chart">...</svg>
  #shadow-root
</th-compare-balance-chart>
```

Comment: Are you sure there is no `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"` in the SVG tag? Unless that document is pre-processed in some way and `#shadow-root` is replaced by XML elements, an XPath processor will simply view `#shadow-root` as a sibling text node of `<svg>`. You can also try `//th-compare-balance-chart//svg` which will skip anything before the `svg` tag, or `//th-compare-balance-chart//*[local-name()='svg']` in case a namespace declaration is somehow inserted as well.

Comment: Ugh, neither of those paths work. The th-compare-balance-chart and it's children are dynamically added to the page so it's not in the page source. But I'm looking in the elements inspector in chrome and I see other attributes on the svg element but no xmlns attribute. I'm starting to think that it has something to do with the way Polymer is rendering things.

Comment: Another reason I think it has to do with Polymers rending is because using getAttribute(<polymer-element>, <some-attribute-visible-in-the-inspector>, callback(result)) result.value is null.

Comment: Try to see what you get using `//th-compare-balance-chart/*` and `//th-compare-balance-chart//*`

Comment: Unable to locate element: "//th-compare-balance-chart//*" using: xpath and Unable to locate element: "//th-compare-balance-chart/*" using: xpath... Can I really access those elements! That's pretty lame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your command is using the default CSS selection. To switch to XPath use:

```
browser.
    .useXpath()
    .getAttribute('//th-compare-chart/svg', 'width', function(svgWidth) {
    ...
})
```

Comment: Okay, it's now searching the DOM using Xpath selectors but it can't seem to locate any children of my element or any elements by id. For example it can find '//th-compare-chart' but not '//th-compare-chart/svg' and it can't find '//svg[@id="#chart"]' either. My syntax looks correct compared to all the references I can find. Am I missing a nightwatch.js or selenium xPath requirement?

Comment: Can you add your XML to the question? There might be an `xmlns` declaration for `<svg>`, that would require that you either register the namespace and prefix the selectors, or ignore it (using `*[local-name()='svg']` instead of `svg`). And your `id` would probably contain `chart` and not `#chart`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. I've added the markup to the original question.

Answer (score 3):

You're running into [the Shadow DOM](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/) here. The shadow dom is used to prevent unintended interactions between a web component and the rest of the page, and to isolate the implementation of a component from its interface.

In practice this means that querying for elements will not pass through a shadow dom boundary unless you explicitly specify that you intend for this to happen. With CSS selectors this is accomplished through the `::shadow` and `/deep/` operators. So this should work:

```
browser
.getAttribute('th-compare-chart::shadow svg', 'width', function(svgWidth) {

...
})

// or

browser
.getAttribute('th-compare-chart /deep/ svg', 'width', function(svgWidth) {

...
})
```

I'm not familiar enough with XPath to tell you what operators it has for piercing shadow dom boundaries. I can tell you that when you get hold of a `th-compare-chart` element you can dive into its shadow dom using the `.shadowRoot` attribute, and query that in the normal way. e.g. `document.querySelector('th-compare-chart').shadowRoot.querySelector('svg')`

Note that not all browsers implement the shadow dom. Polymer will still work in all modern browsers, but you may have to do some additional work for your selectors to work across browsers with and without shadow dom support. [More info on shadow dom support](http://caniuse.com/shadowdom).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This seemed really promising and I tried a couple of different combinations and they all yield this error message: 'stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document' Though it didn't work I feel like this has definitely helped a lot.

Comment: Oh I didn't realize nightwatch used web driver (/ selenium). For reasons I don't entirely follow you'll need to call `switchToSubTree` on the shadowRoot. Link to the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#switching-to-hosted-shadow-doms

More explanation: It's not uncommon for libraries to get confused and think that shadow dom elements aren't part of the larger document because if you repeatedly get the `.parent` of a node in the shadow dom you end up with the shadowRoot. To traverse to its host node you need to access `.host`

Comment: This is really helpful. Is there a way to interface directly with the WebDriver that's used with nightwatch.js? Or is there any examples of how switchToSubTree would be used in this context? I can't seem to find anything else about it, other than the link that you provided. If I'm correct, I believe it would need to be added to the interface that's provided in protocol.js?

Comment: I know I'm asking you to spell it out for me, but I'm very new to all of this.

Comment: It doesn't look like nightwatch has support for asserting about shadow dom elements :/. I've added an issue to their issue tracker for this: https://github.com/beatfactor/nightwatch/issues/192